# Find elapsed time in LIFO manner in MySQL

Tags: mysql

We have been given a table and the objective is to find elapsed time for a given task.

```
Task | Event | Timestamp
-------------------------
1    | begin |    1
1    | end   |    2
2    | begin |    3
2    | end   |    4
2    | begin |    5
2    | begin |    6
2    | begin |    7
2    | end   |    8
2    | end   |    9
2    | end   |    10
```

The query result should look like this:

```
Task | Begin | End | Elapsed
----------------------------
1    |   1   |  2  |   1
2    |   3   |  4  |   1
2    |   5   |  10 |   5
2    |   6   |  9  |   3
2    |   7   |  8  |   1
```

For a given task, the last begin should be associated with first end. Thus for task2, 5 => 10, 6 => 9 and 7 => 8. We can assume that for a given task there are equal begin and end events. Does anyone know how we can achieve this using MySQL?

Comment: What's your mysql version?

Comment: What have you tried so far and where did you get stuck?

Comment: How do you order the data in the first table?  If it's arbitrarily then I don't see how for task 2 you can get `3 => 4`, `5 => 10`, etc. because they are only ordered that way by chance

Comment: @Akina - "_there are equal begin and end events_"

Comment: *We can assume that for a given task there are equal begin and end events* What if the amount of `begin` is less than the amount of `end` at some `timestamp` value? Or we can assume that this is impossible too?

Comment: @Akina LIFO stands for last in first out and records are ordered by timestamp.

Comment: @Shadow I'd like to see "the source data is correct and the solution exists with the guarantee" from OP.

Comment: @Akina the source data and the result table add up in terms of sorting and pairing of begins and ends with what the OP described in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT task, timestamp1 `Begin`, timestamp2 `End`, timestamp2 - timestamp1 Elapsed
FROM (
SELECT (@event1 := CASE WHEN `event` = 'begin'
                        THEN @event1 + 1
                        ELSE @event1 - 1 
                        END) + (`event` = 'end') event_num,
       @cluster1 := @cluster1 + (`event` = 'begin') * (@event1 = 1) cluster,
       task, 
       `event` event1,
       `timestamp` timestamp1
FROM test
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cluster1:=0, @event1:=0) init_vars
ORDER BY task, `timestamp`
) t1
JOIN (
SELECT (@event2 := CASE WHEN `event` = 'begin'
                        THEN @event2 + 1
                        ELSE @event2 - 1 
                        END) + (`event` = 'end') event_num,
       @cluster2 := @cluster2 + (`event` = 'begin') * (@event2 = 1) cluster,
       task, 
       `event` event2,
       `timestamp` timestamp2
FROM test
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cluster2:=0, @event2:=0) init_vars
ORDER BY task, `timestamp`
) t2 USING (event_num, cluster, task)
WHERE event1 = 'begin'
  AND event2 = 'end'
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=5fd4d962794c8b31e5dd9d626410895f

PS. Gives wrong output on version 8+.